# Left join with nearest value without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to achieve in MS SQL something like below, using 2 tables and through join instead of iteration.

From table A, I want each row to identify from table B which in the list is their nearest value, and when value has been selected, that value cannot re-used. Please help if you've done something like this before. Thank you in advance! #SOreadyToAsk

[image]

Comment: So this is an iteration of sorts where it needs to evaluate record by record?

Comment: yes but a no? well seriously, I want to avoid "cursor" or "while" in this case. If there's anyway possible like a flags as work around or anything, that should be fine.

Comment: _and when value has been selected, that value cannot re-used_ - this is the deal-breaker for using a compound select. I would do this in a stored procedure, probably using a temporary table

Comment: yup, temp table is actually ok but then again the challenge here is that, the function must be able to identify its relationship to its corresponding nearest value, and may remove the duplicate relationship afterwards I guess..

Comment: "may remove the duplicate relationship afterwards I guess" - what does that mean?

Comment: the case was to match nearest without duplicate match, then its just a suggestion that you may remove the duplicate after matching, instead of compressing everything in one big query. hopefully this sends my message well.

Comment: may be able to use recursive cte

Comment: "nearest value" means it can be bigger or smaller than the value in table A?

Comment: @PradeepKumar when you compare the ABS(value A - value B) and order it, you can get which is the nearest value.

Comment: i think this can't be done without iteration (or maybe with recursion (cte's), but the performance would still be poor if done this way too) because you would need to store old results to determine if a number has already been taken.  you would be able to write a query to assign the first batch of numbers, then  repeat with numbers not already taken, but you would have to program the number of repetitions manually.  if this can simply be done with joins, i wouldn't mind seeing the solution out of interest, but my 2 cents is that cursors are the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly believe **THIS IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE** because I am bypassing the policy SQL made for itself that functions with side-effects (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) is a **NO**, but due to the fact that I want solve this without resulting to iteration options, I came up with this and gave me better view of things now.

```
create table tablea
(
    num     INT,
    val     MONEY
)

create table tableb
(
    num     INT,
    val     MONEY
)
```

I created a hard-table temp which I shall drop from time-to-time.

```
if((select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'temp_tableb') is not null) begin drop table temp_tableb end
select * into temp_tableb from tableb
```

I created a function that executes xp_cmdshell (this is where the side-effect bypassing happens)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNearestMatch] 
(
    @ParamValue MONEY
)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnNum MONEY
    , @ID INT

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @ID = num
        , @ReturnNum = val
    FROM temp_tableb ORDER BY ABS(val - @ParamValue)

    DECLARE @SQL varchar(500)
    SELECT @SQL = 'osql -S' + @@servername + ' -E -q "delete from test..temp_tableb where num = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150),@ID) + ' "'

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQL

    RETURN @ReturnNum

END
```

and my usage in my query simply looks like this.

```
-- initialize temp
if((select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'temp_tableb') is not null) begin drop table temp_tableb end
select * into temp_tableb from tableb
-- query nearest match
select
    *
    , dbo.GetNearestMatch(a.val) AS [NearestValue]
from tablea a
```

and gave me this..

[image]

Comment: I see what you did there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Below is a set-based solution using CTEs and windowing functions.

The `ranked_matches` CTE assigns a closest match rank for each row in `TableA` along with a closest match rank for each row in `TableB`, using the `index` value as a tie breaker.

The `best_matches` CTE returns rows from `ranked_matches` that have the best rank (rank value 1) for both rankings.

Finally, the outer query uses a `LEFT JOIN` from `TableA` to the to the `best_matches` CTE to include the `TableA` rows that were not assigned a best match due to the closes match being already assigned.

Note that this does not return a match for the index 3 TableA row indicated in your sample results.  The closes match for this row is TableB index 3, a difference of 83.  However, that TableB row is a closer match to the TableA index 2 row, a difference of 14 so it was already assigned.  Please clarify you question if this isn't what you want.  I think this technique can be tweaked accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA(
      [index] int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TableA PRIMARY KEY
    , value int
    );
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB(
      [index] int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TableB PRIMARY KEY
    , value int
    );
INSERT  INTO dbo.TableA
        ( [index], value )
VALUES  ( 1, 123 ),
        ( 2, 245 ),
        ( 3, 342 ),
        ( 4, 456 ),
        ( 5, 608 );

INSERT  INTO dbo.TableB
        ( [index], value )
VALUES  ( 1, 152 ),
        ( 2, 159 ),
        ( 3, 259 );

WITH 
      ranked_matches AS (
        SELECT 
              a.[index] AS a_index
            , a.value AS a_value
            , b.[index] b_index
            , b.value AS b_value
            , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.[index] ORDER BY ABS(a.Value - b.value), b.[index]) AS a_match_rank
            , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.[index] ORDER BY ABS(a.Value - b.value), a.[index]) AS b_match_rank
        FROM dbo.TableA AS a
        CROSS JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
    )
    , best_matches AS (
        SELECT
              a_index
            , a_value
            , b_index
            , b_value
        FROM ranked_matches
        WHERE
                a_match_rank = 1
            AND b_match_rank= 1
    )
SELECT
      TableA.[index] AS a_index
    , TableA.value AS a_value
    , best_matches.b_index
    , best_matches.b_value
FROM dbo.TableA
LEFT JOIN best_matches ON
    best_matches.a_index = TableA.[index]
ORDER BY
    TableA.[index];
```

**EDIT:**

Although this method uses CTEs, recursion is not used and is therefore not limited to 32K recursions.  There may be room for improvement here from a performance perspective, though.

Comment: CTE sure definitely is an option however I cannot imagine forming the results with greater than the max possible recursions, thanks for the time though as I too, not giving up to this type of case.

Comment: @kenlacoste, this is a true set-based solution without recursion and the associated limitations.  I don't want to imply that this will perform well with large tables because of the inherent need to calculate the ABS before ranking;  full scans will be needed.  There may be other solutions that can perform better.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I didn't look in details in your query, but unfortunately it doesn't return correct result. It returns row 3: `a_index: 3, a_value: 342, b_index: NULL, b_value: NULL` instead of `b_index: 2, b_value: 159`. Sorry, I didn't notice that you wrote it in the answer. Yes, that's the challenge.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, the expected results in the question are different from the question, which is why I asked for clarification.  The question says from Table A, identify from Table B which is the nearest value without reusing values. The sample results appear to be from Table B identify the nearest Table A value, or the next nearest Table A value when the Table A is already used.  The Table A value is not the nearest to the Table B value in the latter case.

Comment: @kenlacoste, please add few more rows to your sample data with expected result to illustrate better what you really need. Maybe, explain also step-by-step, row-by-row how and why the result is such.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible without a cursor.

Even if it is possible to do it without a cursor, it would definitely require self-joins, maybe more than once. As a result performance is likely to be poor, likely worse than straight-forward cursor. And it is likely that it would be hard to understand the logic and later maintain this code. Sometimes cursors are useful.

The main difficulty is this part of the question:

> when value has been selected, that value cannot re-used.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389297/create-a-table-with-unique-values-from-another-table/32390678#32390678) just few days ago.

The logic is straight-forward. Cursor loops through all rows of table `A` and with each iteration adds one row to the temporary destination table. To determine the `value` to add I use `EXCEPT` operator that takes all `values` from the table `B` and removes from them all `values` that have been used before. My solution assumes that there are no duplicates in `value` in table `B`. `EXCEPT` operator removes duplicates. If `values` in table `B` are not unique, then temporary table would hold unique `indexB` instead of `valueB`, but main logic remains the same.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4c58/1/0).

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @TA TABLE (idx int, value int);
INSERT INTO @TA (idx, value) VALUES
(1, 123),
(2, 245),
(3, 342),
(4, 456),
(5, 608);

DECLARE @TB TABLE (idx int, value int);
INSERT INTO @TB (idx, value) VALUES
(1, 152),
(2, 159),
(3, 259);
```

**Main query** inserts result into temporary table `@TDst`. It is possible to write that `INSERT` without using explicit variable `@CurrValueB`, but it looks a bit cleaner with variable.

```
DECLARE @TDst TABLE (idx int, valueA int, valueB int);

DECLARE @CurrIdx int;
DECLARE @CurrValueA int;
DECLARE @CurrValueB int;

DECLARE @iFS int;
DECLARE @VarCursor CURSOR;
SET @VarCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT idx, value
    FROM @TA
    ORDER BY idx;

OPEN @VarCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrIdx, @CurrValueA;
SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
WHILE @iFS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @CurrValueB = 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Diff.valueB
        FROM
            (
                SELECT B.value AS valueB
                FROM @TB AS B

                EXCEPT -- remove values that have been selected before

                SELECT Dst.valueB
                FROM @TDst AS Dst
            ) AS Diff
        ORDER BY ABS(Diff.valueB - @CurrValueA)
    );

    INSERT INTO @TDst (idx, valueA, valueB)
    VALUES (@CurrIdx, @CurrValueA, @CurrValueB);

    FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrIdx, @CurrValueA;
    SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
END;

CLOSE @VarCursor;
DEALLOCATE @VarCursor;

SELECT * FROM @TDst ORDER BY idx;
```

**Result**

```
idx    valueA    valueB
1      123       152
2      245       259
3      342       159
4      456       NULL
5      608       NULL
```

It would help to have the following indexes:

`TableA` - `(idx) include (value)`, because we `SELECT idx, value ORDER BY idx`;

`TableB` - `(value) unique`, Temp destination table - `(valueB) unique filtered NOT NULL`, to help `EXCEPT`. So, it may be better to have a temporary #table for result (or permanent table) instead of table variable, because table variables can't have indexes.

---

**Another possible method** would be to delete a row from table `B` (from original or from a copy) as its value is inserted into result. In this method we can avoid performing `EXCEPT` again and again and it could be faster overall, especially if it is OK to leave table `B` empty in the end. Still, I don't see how to avoid cursor and processing individual rows in sequence.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/949c5/1/0)

```
DECLARE @TDst TABLE (idx int, valueA int, valueB int);

DECLARE @CurrIdx int;
DECLARE @CurrValueA int;

DECLARE @iFS int;
DECLARE @VarCursor CURSOR;
SET @VarCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT idx, value
    FROM @TA
    ORDER BY idx;

OPEN @VarCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrIdx, @CurrValueA;
SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
WHILE @iFS = 0
BEGIN
    WITH
    CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) B.idx, B.value
        FROM @TB AS B
        ORDER BY ABS(B.value - @CurrValueA)
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE
    OUTPUT @CurrIdx, @CurrValueA, deleted.value INTO @TDst;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrIdx, @CurrValueA;
    SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
END;

CLOSE @VarCursor;
DEALLOCATE @VarCursor;

SELECT
    A.idx
    ,A.value AS valueA
    ,Dst.valueB
FROM
    @TA AS A
    LEFT JOIN @TDst AS Dst ON Dst.idx = A.idx
ORDER BY idx;
```

Comment: Could also do it with a `WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 UPDATE...` which is not too different to a cursor but at least requires less variables

Comment: yeah done the same exact thing with both cursor and while. Still hoping there's a way though, i'm giving this an UP being the same page as me. Thank you

Comment: @kenlacoste, Well, each subsequent value that you choose depends (indirectly) on all previous choices. Similar as in running totals, but you need to examine not just one previous value, but all previous values. Even if you were using SQL Server 2012+, which has extended significantly what you can do with window functions, I don't see an efficient set-based solution. Let's see if someone comes up with a good idea. Maybe recursive...

Comment: If I understand correctly you can save some effort in the `WHILE` solution by marking (updating) rows you have used, then in any subsequent select, use a WHERE clause to ignore them. Again it's a loop based on`WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 `. i.e. while no more work to do. You don't need to remember where you are in the loop or anything like that.

Comment: Another possible method would be to delete a row from table B (from original or from a copy) <- this gave me an idea. Thanks!