# Create a table with unique values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio. I have table -

```
+--------+----------+
| Num_ID | Alpha_ID |
+--------+----------+
|   1    |    A     |
|   1    |    B     |
|   1    |    C     |
|   2    |    B     |
|   2    |    C     |
|   3    |    A     |
|   4    |    C     |
|   5    |    A     |
|   5    |    B     |
+--------+----------+
```

I want to create another table with 2 columns from this table so that column_1 gives Unique values in Num_ID (i.e. 1,2,3,4 and so on) and column_2 gives Unique values in Alpha_ID (A, B, C and so on).

But if an alphabet has already occurred, it should not occur again. So the output will be something like this -

```
Col_1  Col_2
================
1     -    A
----------------
2     -    B
----------------
3      -   NULL (as A has been chosen by 1, it cannot occur next to 3)
----------------
4    -     C
----------------
5     -    NULL (both 5 A and 5 B cannot be chosen as A and B were picked up by 1 and 2) 
----------------
```

Hope that makes sense. 
I would like to clarify that the IDs in the input table are not numerical as I have shown, but both Num_ID and Alpha_ID are complex strings. I have simplified them to 1,2,3,... and A, B, C .... for the purpose of this question

Comment: Might want to work on your formatting here. This is not readable.

Comment: I started editing this but could not think of a descriptive name for the question, so I kinda moved on.

Comment: I tried to fix the title; if it's wrong, please correct it.

Comment: When there are many values for the same num the first one is picked?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please take a look at this question, thanks.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen notifications do not work unless the user you're notifying has posted or edited on the question.

Comment: That explains why he never responds to me.  It looks @Wewestthemenace managed to get it right though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think it's not right yet. Try inserting (3, 'C'). I'll have to make updates later, after my lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this could be done without a cursor.
I added few more rows to your sample data to test how it works with other cases.

The logic is straight-forward. At first get a list of all distinct values of `Num_ID`. Then loop through them and with each iteration add one row to the destination table. To determine the `Alpha_ID` value to add I'll use `EXCEPT` operator that takes all available `Alpha_ID` values for the current `Num_ID` from the source table and removes from them all values that have been used before.

It is possible to write that `INSERT` without using explicit variable `@CurrAlphaID`, but it looks a bit cleaner with variable.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96e69c/2/0).

```
DECLARE @TSrc TABLE (Num_ID varchar(10), Alpha_ID varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @TSrc (Num_ID, Alpha_ID) VALUES
('1', 'A'),
('1', 'B'),
('1', 'C'),
('2', 'B'),
('2', 'C'),
('3', 'A'),
('3', 'C'),
('4', 'A'),
('4', 'C'),
('5', 'A'),
('5', 'B'),
('5', 'C'),
('6', 'D'),
('6', 'E');

DECLARE @TDst TABLE (Num_ID varchar(10), Alpha_ID varchar(10));

DECLARE @CurrNumID varchar(10);
DECLARE @CurrAlphaID varchar(10);

DECLARE @iFS int;
DECLARE @VarCursor CURSOR;
SET @VarCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT Num_ID
    FROM @TSrc
    ORDER BY Num_ID;

OPEN @VarCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrNumID;
SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
WHILE @iFS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @CurrAlphaID = 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Diff.Alpha_ID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT Src.Alpha_ID
                FROM @TSrc AS Src
                WHERE Src.Num_ID = @CurrNumID

                EXCEPT

                SELECT Dst.Alpha_ID
                FROM @TDst AS Dst
            ) AS Diff
        ORDER BY Diff.Alpha_ID
    );

    INSERT INTO @TDst (Num_ID, Alpha_ID) 
    VALUES (@CurrNumID, @CurrAlphaID);

    FETCH NEXT FROM @VarCursor INTO @CurrNumID;
    SET @iFS = @@FETCH_STATUS;
END;

CLOSE @VarCursor;
DEALLOCATE @VarCursor;

SELECT * FROM @TDst;
```

**Result**

```
Num_ID    Alpha_ID
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         NULL
5         NULL
6         D
```

Having index on `(Num_ID, Alpha_ID)` on the source table would help. Having index on `(Alpha_ID)` on the destination table would help as well.

Comment: I thought that perhaps we could use a recursive CTE so that we can track which alpha values were already taken as we select, but you cannot use recursion in a sub select so it doesn't work unfortunately. I guess a CURSOR is the only option.

Comment: @plalx, maybe it is possible to do it without a cursor, but it would definitely require self-joins, maybe more than once. As a result performance likely to be poor, likely worse than straight-forward cursor. And it is likely that it would be hard to understand the logic and later maintain this code. Sometimes cursors are useful.

Comment: I think this is where the use of `CURSOR` might be acceptable. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've made something not through a recursion (cursor or a while)

First, I created a table with rows.

```
create table #tmptest
(
    Num_ID int
    , Alpha_ID varchar(50)
)

insert into #tmptest (Num_ID, Alpha_ID) values
(1,'A'),
(1,'B'),
(1,'C'),
(2,'B'),
(2,'C'),
(3,'A'),
(4,'C'),
(5,'A'),
(5,'B')

// this one, with row column
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Num_ID ORDER BY Num_ID ASC) as row
    , *
INTO #tmp_withrow
FROM #tmptest
```

and these were the results

[image]

Lastly, I made an inner query (could possibly be a left join or better).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Num_ID
    , (
        SELECT 
            TOP 1
                Alpha_ID
        FROM #tmp_withrow in1
        WHERE
            in1.Num_ID = t.Num_ID
        AND in1.Alpha_ID NOT IN (
            SELECT
                Alpha_ID 
            FROM #tmp_withrow in2
            WHERE
                in2.Num_ID < in1.Num_ID
            AND in2.row = 1
        )
        ORDER BY in1.Num_ID ASC
    ) AS [NonRepeatingAlpha]
from #tmptest t
```

and these were the results

[image]

Note : I created a flag (`row`) which will allow you to query all less than the ID's you're in (`in2.Num_ID < in1.Num_ID`) then find out what letters where already used (`in2.row = 1`) and then select / avoid all letters that has already been used from the other Num_ID (

```
WHERE in1.Num_ID = t.Num_ID 
  AND in1.Alpha_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT
        Alpha_ID 
    FROM #tmp_withrow in2
    WHERE
        in2.Num_ID < in1.Num_ID
        AND in2.row = 1
```

)

I hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't look into your query in details, but add `(3,'C')` to your test data and you'll see that result is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: yeah, my apologies, but i'll get back on this! :)